# Design principle behind a non-stack blowing parser

Tags: c++, parsing, c++17, stack-overflow

I'm designing a JSON parser for my embedded system. It should come with the protection against stack overflows, meaning that there should be no nested function calls (recursion) or growing storage information. *Also no dynamic allocation!* How would I in general design such a parser?

In general I can't really figure out how to save contextual information to return to after processing the lower layers. I could of course just parse the upper layers and then start from the beginning to dive down to the second layer, but that would be really inefficient.

Comment: "how to save contextual information" You can save it in an explicit stack, as in `std::stack`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I could do that, but that would require dynamic allocation which I want to avoid :) sorry, didn't mention it, added to the description now.

Comment: You cannot parse a context-free language such as json in fixed memory. That's the law of the nature. Sorry about that.

Comment: That would be difficult, since you generally cannot know the exact dimensions of the JSON file at compile time. The best thing I can imagine right now is, to prepare a 'sufficiently large buffer' and simply fail your parsing if the parsed information exceeds that limit.

Comment: You cannot parse a context-free language (CFL) like JSON without a stack. Chomsky 1956. NB Nested function calls do not in themselves constitute recursion.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I'm aware of the limitations of static allocations, the parsing is supposed to just break if it would blow preallocated memory. But on embedded, knowing the limitations is better than just hoping that heap will be sufficient.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium: That's exactly my intention

Comment: So write your own static fixed stack. Normally allocation failure would throw and you would just handle the exception, but if you run with exceptions disabled, the standard library is nearly useless.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes, exceptions are disabled, but you can still use a lot of stl even though you have to pass on dynamically allocated containers. Also, dynamic allocation is not really runtime efficient and I avoid it where possible. As for the JSON, std::string has the amazing property of storing small strings on stack which fits my cause. Of course, if you go overboard you need to be made aware that dynamic allocations are happening.

Comment: Dynamic allocation compared to the cost of putting data onto the wire and getting it off again and parsing it is infinitely efficient.

Comment: @user207421 Of course, but I need my CPU cycles for other stuff on the device :)

Comment: You can build your own stack its just harder. It will be much easier to use recursion (as the application stack is doing the work you would do manually). You can protect yourself by having a parameter that defines the depth of your recursion, then bail if it gets too deep.

Comment: To parse generic JSON (that could be any shape) then recursion is the way to go. But if your JSON is a fixed format for a specific application (the config file for your app etc). Then it can be a much simpler application where you read exactly what you need only.

Comment: Is your application safety-critical? Does anything significant (by your definition) depend on it running or failing gracefully? If not, you can simply use recursion and let it fail and crash due to stack overflow if the parsed JSON is too complicated. BTW, what's your plan for handling situations when you cannot parse the JSON?

Comment: @MartinYork The format is actually fixed but not the depth. Anyway, I want to make it a generic parser. But you're right that it's the same if you use a stack or if you fail at a certain stack depth, so I could do it the later way

Comment: @KrzysiekKarbowiak Stack overflow is not an option as it will crash the whole application and restart my system. It needs to fail gracefully so it will just issue an error and abort. The advantage with automatic memory is that I don't need to do the cleanup :)